# role of [:] in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

What is the role of `[:]` in this program:

```
import numpy as np
l=np.array([[0,0,0,0],
            [4,5,6,7],
            [7,8,9,8]])
out[:]=np.nanstd(l, axis=0)
print(out)
```

If I write the third line of the code just like this (i.e., without `[:]`):

```
out=np.nanstd(l, axis=0)
```

I'd get the same result. So, what is the role of [:] and in what context does it make a difference?

Comment: First of all, your code will raise a NameError, since `out` is not defined.  Second, your "alternative" for the third line is the same as what you already put in your first example.

Comment: @BernBarn I'm running the code in Jupyter and there is no error. I get the array of the result: [ 2.86744176  3.29983165  3.74165739  3.55902608]. And I edited the typo in the alternative.

Comment: That's a bad `duplicate`

Comment: Perhaps you've set up the `out` variable in your Jupyter setup, but otherwise, this can't run. The slicing syntax does make a difference, but without knowing more about `out`, no-one can't say.

Answer (score 1):

A `Jupyter/ipython` session maintains an `Out` dictionary that contains history.  But `Out[:]` would give an error.

In a fresh session, this produces an error:

```
In [731]: out[:]=np.array([1,2,3])
....
NameError: name 'out' is not defined
```

But if I first create an `out`, the `out[:]` syntax works

```
In [732]: out=np.array([1,2,3])
In [733]: out
Out[733]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [734]: out[:]=np.array([4,5,6])
In [735]: out
Out[735]: array([4, 5, 6])
```

The first creates an `out` variable, in this case as an array.  The second replaces the values in `out` with new ones.  The number of values in the replacement will have to match the shape of the original.

If `out` is initially (or redefined as) a list, the `[:]` assignment also works, replacing all the values with new ones (which don't have to match).

```
In [736]: out=[1,2,3]
In [737]: out[:]=[4,5]
In [738]: out
Out[738]: [4, 5]
```

With a list `out=...` and `out[:]=...` are quite similar, and we'd have to look at the `id(out)` before and after to notice a difference.

But the basic point is `out = ...` assigns a new object to the variable.  `out[:] = ...` assigns new values to an existing object.  The exact action in the 2nd case depends on the class of that object.